# write two lists of parcelables into parcel in Android

Tags: java, android, list, parcelable, parcel

I have object Contact:

```
public class Contact implements Parcelable
```

with properties:

```
private List<EmailAttribute> contact_emails_attributes = new ArrayList<EmailAttribute>();
private List<PhoneAttribute> contact_phones_attributes = new ArrayList<PhoneAttribute>();
```

EmailAttribute and PhoneAttribute implemets Parcelable.

How to write contact's properties into parcel and read them ? I was looking for solution long time but I have found no solution how to write different parcelables into parcel.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by using the methods [Parcel.writeTypedList(List)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeTypedList%28java.util.List%3CT%3E%29) and [Parcel.readTypedList(List, Creator)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#readTypedList%28java.util.List%3CT%3E,%20android.os.Parcelable.Creator%3CT%3E%29) like this:

Read it from the Parcel:

```
public Contact(Parcel in){
   contact_emails_attributes = in.readTypedList(contact_emails_attributes, EmailAttribute.CREATOR);
   contact_phones_attributes = in.readTypedList(contact_phones_attributes, PhoneAttribute.CREATOR);
}
```

Write it to the Parcel:

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeTypedList(contact_emails_attributes); 
    dest.writeTypedList(contact_phones_attributes);
}
```